# How to add select all option in ngx-select-ex multiple control?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I need to show select all option to users to enable selecting all options loaded into ngx-select-ex multiple control.

Comment: I am not sure how others but I do not understand what you are asking for, do you mind clearing this up? Thanks

Comment: It is a angularjs dropdown component. I'm trying to add select all option into it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-ex

Comment: oh, then I think it's not about angularjs but angular 4+ 
Do you mind changing tags? 
I don't know angular 4